# i want to get the employees details from employee table who are getting highest salary job wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called as employee table. I want to get names of employees who are getting highest salaries from their respective jobs.

I have tried following query.

```
select ename from employee
where sal in 
(select job,max(sal) from employee
group by job)
```

But it gives an error saying

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that your subselect returns rows with two values (job, max(sal)), and you're trying to match the salary to that. You need to only return one value in order to be able to use 'value in (subselect)' since there's no way to tell which of the values returned to match to your value.

You can try something like to get only the name:

```
select e1.ename from employee e1
join (select job, max(value) as m from employee
    group by job) as e2 on e1.job = e2.job
where e1.value = e2.m
```

What this does is use a select as a temporary join table containing each job and its maximum salary, and joins your employee table with it based on the employee's job, and only selects an employee if his salary is equal to the maximum salary of his job

Comment: The condition in the `WHERE` can the moved to the `JOIN`: `on e1.job = e2.job AND e1.value = e2.m`

Answer (score 0):

You could left join the employee table back to itself, with the join condition being a salary higher than the current row, then exclude all rows where that matches

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Employee E1
  LEFT JOIN Employee E2 ON (E2.job = E1.job and E2.salary > E1.salary)
WHERE E2.name is null
```

That will give you the list of all employee's that don't have anyone else in their same job with a higher salary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simpler query:

```sql
select ename, job, sal from emp where sal in(select max(sal) from emp group by job);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the highest paid employees job-wise:

```
select job,First_name,Last_name,salary 
from Employee 
where salary IN 
    (
    select MAX(salary) 
    from Employee 
    GROUP BY job
    );
```